# What does the "API Throttling" and "API Throttling Warnings" mean?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, terminology, throttling

In app insights, under API->Activity & Errors there are sections pertaining to: "Api Throttling" and "API Throttling Warnings". But I can't find documentation for what these sections mean and how to interpret them anywhere.

1. What are the time values shown next to each section? i.e. Api Throttling - x minutes?
2. What is this "fraction of budget"? And why do the %'s never seem to add up? :-P

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210701362295828#Why-is-my-app-getting-rate-limited?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932700/query-optimization-and-api-throttling

Answer (score 1):

> What are the time values shown next to each section? i.e. Api Throttling - x minutes?

How long you have to wait until throttling ends

> What is this "fraction of budget"? And why do the %'s never seem to add up?

The ratio of your total units to your consumed units

**References**

- [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)
- [Ben Alman » jQuery throttle / debounce: Sometimes, less is more!](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)
- [Throttle and Debounce Patterns in Web Apps](http://www.slideshare.net/almirfilh0/throttle-and-debounce-patterns-in-web-apps)
- [ReactJS : using debounce in react components](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/02/reactjs-using-debounce-in-react-components.html)
- [Delay an action: Debounce and throttle – Rudy Huyn](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2016/03/01/delay-an-action-debounce-and-throttle/)
- [Throttle and Debounce visual explanation](http://caiogondim.github.io/js-debounce-throttle-visual-explanation/)